# how to count number of items in two div and rearrange them in ascending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, compare

So, I want to rearrange two div's which will have some items in the which are dynamic in number structure of the div will be as follows:

> ---DIV A------------------------------DIV B---------------
>
> 1. item 1 --------------------- 1. item 1-----------------
> 2. item 2 --------------------- 2. item 2-----------------
> 3. item 3 -------------------------------------------------

So now I want to count no. of items from both div and then if, as in example, DIV A has more item than DIV B results should look like:
So, I want to rearrange to div's which will have some items in the which are dynamic in number structure of the div will be as follows:

> ---DIV B------------------------------DIV A---------------
>
> 1. item 1 --------------------- 1. item 1-----------------
> 2. item 2 --------------------- 2. item 2-----------------
>
>    -------------------------------3. item 3------------------

i tried to count like follow:

```
jQuery("div").each(function(){
var chk1 = jQuery("div.A").length;
var chk2 = jQuery("div.B").length;

var arr = [{"name" : "DIVA", "count" : chk1}, {"name" : "DIVB", "count" : chk2}];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.count - b.count;
});
console.log(arr);

});
```

Comment: Please provide sample HTML that can be used to illustrate what you want. That will be much more useful to understand what you need than the textual representation you have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var toSort = $(".sort").toArray();

toSort.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.children.length - b.children.length;
});

toSort.forEach(function(div){
  $(document.body).append(div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sort" style="color:green">
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
</div>

<div class="sort" style="color:red">
<p>1</p>
</div>

<div class="sort" style="color:orange">
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
</div>
```

The main thing youre missing is reapplying the sorted order to the DOM, and theres no need to setup a new array, you can work with element references.

Comment: @anudeep gupta wheres the problem? May just use *.selector*

Comment: no the issue is title should come to their respective divs like this https://jsfiddle.net/e6Lxv4fr/2/ where as after the script it comes to be https://jsfiddle.net/e6Lxv4fr/1/

Comment: @anudeep yeah just use $(".selecector").toArray()

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the length of the *children* collection of each `div`, and sort by that. Then replace the current, unsorted content with the sorted content. For that you can use `.appendTo()`:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div.A, div.B').sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).children().length - $(b).children().length;
    }).appendTo('#container');
});
```

```css
.A, .B {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="A">
        <div>1. item A.1</div>
        <div>2. item A.2</div>
        <div>3. item A.3</div>
    </div><div class="B">
        <div>1. item B.1</div>
        <div>2. item B.2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Order longest list to the right</button>
```

Comment: You already accepted an answer, so I suppose you already got the help you needed. ;-)